# Problem executing raw SQL query in Python: sqlalchemy.exc.programmingerror syntax error at or near

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have a query in a python script that creates a materialized view after some tables get created.

Script is something like this:

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

    sql = '''CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema1.view1 AS 
            SELECT t1.a,
              t1.b,
              t1.c,
              t2.x AS d
            FROM schema1.t1 t1
            LEFT JOIN schema1.t2 t2 ON t1.f = t2.f
            UNION ALL
            SELECT t3.a, 
              t3.b, 
              t3.c, 
              t3.d
            FROM schema1.t3 t3;'''

    con=create_engine(db_conn)

    con.execute(sql)
```

The query successfully executes when I run on the database directly.

But when running the script in python, I get an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema"
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what it has an issue with - any ideas?

Comment: Wild guess - did you try removing `schema.` part from the first line of your query? I am not sure if it is necessary to provide it.

Comment: @Ilja No, just notionalizing my actual query. The query completes successfully directly in PostgreSQL, just not via Python/sqlalchemy. Changed to 'schema1' to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Epion don't think this is the issue.

Comment: it's missing a comma after `t1.c`, though I doubt the error message would point so far away from the error

Comment: @JGH just a typo when I typed it in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the weirdest thing. I had copied my query text out of another tool that I use to navigate around my pg DB into VS Code. The last part of the answer by @EOhm gave me the idea to just type the whole thing out in VS Code instead of copy/pasting.

And everything worked.

Even though the pasted text and what I typed appear identical in every way. So apparently there was some invisible formatting causing this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know wether SQLAlchemy suports MView-Creation, but if it should be similiar or done with specific Metadata functions (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/schema.html).

The text function is designed for database indepenendent DML, not DDL. Maybe it works for DDL (I don't know about SQLAlchemy) but by design the syntax is different than when You would execute directly on the database as SQLAlchemy shall abstract the details of databases from user.

If SQLAlchemy does no offer some convenient way for that and You nevertheless have valid reasons to use SQLAlchemy at all, You can just execute the plain SQL Statememt in the dialect the database backend understands, so just omit the sqlalchemies `text` function for the SQL statement, like:

```
   from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

    sql = '''CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.view1 AS 
            SELECT t1.a,
              t1.b,
              t1.c
              t2.x AS d
            FROM schema.t1 t1
            LEFT JOIN schema.t2 t2 ON t1.f = t2.f
            UNION ALL
            SELECT t3.a, 
              t3.b, 
              t3.c, 
              t3.d
            FROM schema.t3 t3;'''

    con=create_engine(db_conn)
    con.raw_connection().cursor().execute(sql)
```

(But of course You have to take care for the backend type then opposed to the SQLAlchemy wrapped statements.)

---

I tested on my pg server without any issues using psycopg2 directly.

```
postgres=# create schema schema;
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# create table schema.t1 (a varchar, b varchar, c varchar, f integer);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# create table schema.t2 (x varchar, f integer);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# create table schema.t3 (a varchar, b varchar, c varchar, d varchar);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# commit;
```

With the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import psycopg2;

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""
            CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.view1 AS
            SELECT t1.a,
              t1.b,
              t1.c,
              t2.x AS d
            FROM schema.t1 t1
            LEFT JOIN schema.t2 t2 ON t1.f = t2.f
            UNION ALL
            SELECT t3.a,
              t3.b,
              t3.c,
              t3.d
            FROM schema.t3 t3;
""")
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

I tested with quite current versions of python3.7/2.7 and current version of psycopg2 module and current libraries (I have 11.5 pg client and 2.8.3 psycopg2) from pgdg installed on a quite recent linux? Can You try to execute directly on psycopg2 like I did?

Also did You make sure Your dots are plain ascii dots as all the other characters in the statement are in this case? (Also keep in mind there can be invisible codepoints in unicode that can cause such sort of problems.) Maybe You can convert Your string to ASCII binary and back to Unicode-String if You are on Python. If it does not raise an error on `.encode('ASCII')` it should be clean.

Comment: Makes no difference if I include text() or not, so removed it from the question.

Comment: OK, try with raw connection instead (see edited last line). I never used postgres/psycopg2 DBAPI myself but if that still does not work I at least can check the same on my side (I'm not willing to get into SQLAlchemy but have the need for python scripts using postgres drivers soon anyway). @Karl

Comment: Thanks - tried that and same error. This is actually a DBAPI or psycopg2 error as far as I can tell, per the docs on sqlalchemy.

Comment: see my answer above - so weird, appreciate your help on this.